# Canonical Partition function of a Boltzmann gas, for non-interacting particles

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

In our lecture, for the canonical partition function of a Boltzmann gas made out of $N$ particles which do not interact it's given:

$$Z=\frac 1 {N!}\Sigma_{\{\vec P_i\}}e^{-\beta\Sigma_{i=1}^N \frac{\vec P_i^2}{2m}}$$

Which is then transformed to:

$$Z=\frac 1 {N!} [\Sigma_{\vec P}e^{-\beta \frac {\vec p^2}{2m}}]^N.$$

I tried to transform the initial equation into the 2nd one but I cannot.

Initially I tried to understand the symbolic: $\Sigma_{\{\vec P_i\}}$, which i think it is a sum over different sets of the monetum values of the particles. What I am saying is:

${{\{\vec P_i\}}}_0$ would be the set that contains all the momentum values ($N$) of all $N$ particles, when the system is in the first microstate, or also known as ground state.

${{\{\vec P_i\}}}_1$ would be the set that contains all the momentum values ($N$) of all $N$ particles, when the system is in the second microstate, or also known as the first excited state.

But I cannot reach the 2nd equation. Can someone help me?

Comment: In the 2nd expression, there should be a $p^2$ in the exponent

Comment: It is easy to visualize for continuum case: $\Sigma_{\{P_i\}} \to \int dp_1\cdots dp_N$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical partition function is the sum of the Boltzmann factor of the Hamiltonian over all the possible microstates at fixed volume and number of particles.

The notation $\sum_{\left\{\vec P_i \right\}}$ is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{\vec P_1}\sum_{\vec P_2} \dots \sum_{\vec P_N}
$$
where each sum is over the whole set of three-dimensional values of each momentum.

Rewriting the starting formula with this more explicit notation makes it easier to understand how one gets the final result:
$$
\sum_{\vec P_1}\sum_{\vec P_2} \dots \sum_{\vec P_N} e^{-\beta\Sigma_{i=1}^N \frac{\vec P_i^2}{2m}} =\sum_{\vec P_1}\sum_{\vec P_2} \dots \sum_{\vec P_N} \prod_i^N e^{-\beta \frac{\vec P_i^2}{2m}}=\prod_i^N \left( \sum_{\vec P_i}e^{-\beta \frac{\vec P_i^2}{2m}} \right) =\left( \sum_{\vec P}e^{-\beta \frac{\vec P^2}{2m}} \right)^N.
$$
Notice that to rewrite the multiple sums of a product as the product of sums (the second equality), each sum over the momentum values must be independent of the others (no constraint over the possible values of ${\vec P}_i$).

Comment: $\Sigma_{\vec P_1}$ represents all the different momentum values that the first particle takes in each different microstate? (In theory ofc, because practically we cannot tell)?

Comment: One more additional question: In your last expression where are you considering the different $\vec P$ values of different particles? If you had 2 particles for example , in your left you would have: $\Sigma_{\vec P_1}e^{-\beta \frac {\vec P_1^2}{2m}} \cdot \Sigma_{\vec P_2}e^{-\beta \frac {\vec P_2^2}{2m}}$ while if you would use the expression in your right side you would have $[\Sigma_{\vec P}e^{-\beta \frac {\vec P^2}{2m}}]$. How do they give us the same result?

Comment: @imbAF as of the first question, yes, one has to sum over all different possible values of the momentum. Actually, one value of the momentum coincides with a one-particle microstate.

Comment: @imbAF about the second question, if you look carefully, there is a power $N$ in the rightmost expression. The name of the summation index doesn't matter. The product of the two sums is exactly the same as the square of just one of them.